I manually build mysql source code and encouter CMake Error at configure.cmake
today, I download the source code of mysql in my Centos stream release 9 just after excuting $ sudo yum upgrade. I have already yum install all dependecy according to the requirment by cmake. however, camke encouter another question and google or chatgpt cannot help.
$ git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server.git
$ sudo cmake . -DFORCE_INSOURE_BUILD=1
CMake Error at configure.cmake:336
No mysys timer supprot detected!
call stack (most recet call first)
Cmakelists.txt:1546 (INCLUDE)
could you please help or give some advice? thanks so much.

I would try it at Ubuntu server

currently I clone the newst code and build successfully.
